# Where on the Web can I find a comprehensive list of rolling-release Linux distros?

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions

Feel free to post any less-well-known rolling distros, but I'm really looking for a comprehensive list. I'm thinking of creating a Wikipedia page "List of rolling-release Linux distributions". If there's already a good list somewhere then would help produce a draft of the Wikipedia page. If there isn't such a list on the Web it highlights the need of gathering that information on a site where most people would look for it.

Wikipedia seemed to me like the obvious choice but suggestions of a better site [preferably, but not necessarily, a wiki] are welcome.

Please don't post Dev.-branches: eg Fedora-Rawhide, Mandriva-Cooker, OpenSuSE-Factory etc.

Also, please don't post the following rolling-distros as I'm already aware of them: Aptosid, LMDE, AnitX;  OpenSuSE-Tumbleweed; Yoper; Foresight; PCLinuxOS; Unity; Arch, ArchBang, Chakra, Kahel; Gentoo & Sabayon; Lunar, Sorcerer, SourceMage.

If any I've mentioned aren't rolling do correct me. I know some might not call AntiX & LMDE rolling as Debian-Testing "cycles". I also know PCLOS & Sabayon can need to be reinstalled (eg when PCLOS re-forks the Mandriva base).

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I use to get information about Linux and BSD distributions:
http://distrowatch.com/

Go to the 
Their search, while great, doesn't have a "rolling-release" option. I would suggest searching by the most recent Linux kernel version by selecting "linux" under their package search. The most recent version of any package is shown in parenthesis.

Searching for linux 2.6.36.2 gave the following:

> Arch Linux: current
>
> Chakra GNU/Linux: 0.4-alpha2
>
> Gentoo Linux: unstable, stable
>
> Linux From Scratch: unstable
>
> Lunar Linux: moonbase
>
> Mandriva Linux: cooker
>
> Parted Magic: 5.8
>
> PLD Linux Distribution: 3.0
>
> Sorcerer: grimoire
>
> T2 SDE: snapshot
>
> Zenwalk Linux: 7.0-alpha

Comment: Thanks for your list. Searching by kernel ver. is a good idea! I should have thought of that!! :-) DistroWatch is my go-to as well BTW. I posted a comment on there suggesting indicating rolling distros + a search option. I might send an email to the maintainer to ask if he has any plans along these lines. DistroWatch is the obvious go-to and I think a lot of Linux users like to roll. My thought of producing a Wikipedia page is really a response to the lack of such on DistroWatch etc. If DistroWatch was a wiki I'd start a page on there.

Comment: @Tuxalot If you need me to 'sign a petition' for DW to have a list of rolling-release distro's, give me a nudge at (my-username) @ gmail. I'll gladly sign :-)

Comment: @Tuxalot: Me too! If there is a place we can lean on distrowatch to add this let me know. I work as a developer on the PLD project and since we don't do releases we kind of fall off the map over there! I'm reachable through the site linked in my profile.

Comment: What are you specifically interested in? Knowing that would go a long way towards scratching your particular itch.